# Add a file generated by run script into the test target compilation list in Xcode

Tags: swift, xcode

I am trying to add an auto-generated file (`Mock.generated.swift` by running `swiftymocky generate`) to my Compile Sources list of my test target.

To do so, I added a Run Script phase before Compile Sources phase as:

`swiftymocky generate`

And I also dragged the generated file `Mock.generated.swift` to my project but delete it from the local disk. (I want to add it by script but I don't know how.) Then the file will show as RED in the project navigator to indicate it's missing.

Then when I build the test target, I see the file `Mock.generated.swift` is back. But I still get the compilation error:

`Build input file cannot be found`

So what's wrong with my attempt? Is it possible to dynamically add file to the Compile Sources list after the file is generated?

Comment: I don't know if this will help, but what I do is have the file already part of the project in a normal location, and do _not_ remove it, and simply have my script modify its contents.

Comment: @matt Thanks. It seems to work. But to keep the file in the local may make it hard to maintain the git change for developers. As we need the file, we can't add it into .gitignore. But it may change very often.

Comment: Maybe, but that is not what you asked.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

1. your `run script` phase should be **before** `Compile Sources` phase
2. you need to add output file paths to `Output Files`.

By doing this you're letting Xcode know that it should wait this script to be finished before capturing the file structure.

[image]

Comment: Thank's a lot! For me XCode put `$(DERIVED_FILE_DIR)` by default, so be careful the `$(SRCROOT)` is really important